# Override what's bundled in webpack based on file extension

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to figure out whether or not webpack can do something like this.  I have some code that I want to be bundled for a specific device.  So I created a ViewFactories.ios.tsx and I also have ViewFactories.tsx.  The problem i'm encountering is that the if I ignore the .ios.tsx in the loader test, it still gets bundled.  I'm using the `ignore-bundler` plugin to ignore the .ios.tsx files, but the reference is just empty. ie:

```
/** still getting loaded here: **/
const ViewFactories_ios_1 = __importDefault(__webpack_require__(/*! ./ViewFactories.ios */ "./build/app/src/modules/layouts/factories/ViewFactories.ios.tsx"));

/*** the referenced section, but blank now ***/
/***/ "./build/app/src/modules/layouts/factories/ViewFactories.ios.tsx":
/*!***********************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./build/app/src/modules/layouts/factories/ViewFactories.ios.tsx ***!
  \***********************************************************************/
/*! dynamic exports provided */
/*! all exports used */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
/***/ }),
```

What I really want is the reference to ViewFactories.tsx instead of ViewFactories.ios.tsx.
Is there some sort of dependency graph in webpack that I can access to tell the loader to use the default instead of the .ios.tsx?

My webpack config:

```
   {
      test: (modulePath) => {
          if (/\.ios\./.test(modulePath)) {
              console.log(modulePath);
              return false;
          }
          return /\.tsx?$/.test(modulePath);
      },
      loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",
      options: {
          configFileName: 'tsconfig.web.json',
          transpileOnly: true,
          errorsAsWarnings: true,
      }
    },
    {
        test: (modulePath) => {
            if (/\.ios\./.test(modulePath)) {
                console.log('Ignored:  ', modulePath);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },
        loader: 'ignore-loader'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Just build two bundles, with shared config options for whatever is the same?

```js
// webpack.config.js for two different bundles

let sharedModuleDef = {
  rules: ...
}

let sharedPlugins = ...

let iosBundle = {
  entry: "src/ios.entry.js",
  output: {
    path: ...
    filename: "ios.bundle.js"
  },
  module: sharedModuleDef,
  ...
};

let everythingElse = {
  entry: "src/main.entry.js",
  output: {
    path: ...
    filename: "standard.bundle.js"
  },
  module: sharedModuleDef,
  ...
};

module.exports = [iosBundle, everythingElse];
```

Comment: the problem is that the main entry point is shared and somewhere down the dependency graph, there's a fork between ios files and the default files.  So i don't think just having a separate entry point will do (unless i'm mistaken).

Comment: You can use something like https://github.com/nippur72/ifdef-loader to actually remove the file itself, but usually the size difference makes that completely unnecessary, given that you probably minify your code, _and_ your server is set to gzip plain text content for transport (...it is set to that, right?)